# Java: Number of specific character reports

Tags: java, string, algorithm, loops, int

**I've made a program to count the number of each letters in a phrase**

What I want the resulting text to return is

> Enter a phrase
>
> "Cow goes to the market"
>
> There are 1 C('s), 3 O('s), 1 W('s), 1 G('s), 3 E('s), 1 S('s), 3 T('s).. /* you get the gist */ in your phrase.

I want the results to be concatenated into a string instead of just a multi-lined report.

```
import java.util.*;

public class charCount 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    //Prompt for user entry
    System.out.println("Enter a phrase: ");
    String letterN = keyboard.nextLine();

    charCount(letterN);
  }


public static int charCount(String letterN)
{ //variable initializations 
   
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z;
    a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = i = j = k = l = m = n = o = p = q = r = s = t = u = v = w = x = y = z = 0;

    int total = 0;
    total += 1;

//for loop 
for(int countN = 0; countN < letterN.length(); countN++) {
    switch(letterN.charAt(countN)) {
     case 'a':
        a++;
        break;
     case 'b':
        b++;
        break;
     case 'c':
    c++;
    break;
     case 'd':
    d++;
    break;
     case 'e':
    e++;
    break;
     case 'f':
    f++;
    break;
     case 'g':
        g++;
        break;
     case 'h':
        h++;
        break;
     case 'i':
    i++;
    break;
     case 'j':
    j++;
    break;
     case 'k':
    k++;
    break;
     case 'l':
    l++;
    break;
     case 'm':
        m++;
        break;
     case 'n':
        n++;
        break;
     case 'o':
    o++;
    break;
     case 'p':
    p++;
    break;
     case 'q':
    q++;
    break;
     case 'r':
    r++;
    break;
     case 's':
    s++;
    break;
     case 't':
    t++;
    break;
     case 'u':
    u++;
    break;
     case 'v':
    v++;
    break;
     case 'w':
    w++;
    break;
     case 'x':
    x++;
    break;
     case 'y':
    y++;
    break;
     case 'z':
    z++;
    break;
      
    }
    
}

    //Console logs
    System.out.println("Below are the individual character counts for your string");
    System.out.println("A: " + a);
    System.out.println("B: " + b);
    System.out.println("C: " + c);
    System.out.println("D: " + d);
    System.out.println("E: " + e);
    System.out.println("F: " + f);
    System.out.println("G: " + g);
    System.out.println("H: " + h);
    System.out.println("I: " + i);
    System.out.println("J: " + j);
    System.out.println("K: " + k);
    System.out.println("L: " + l);
    System.out.println("M: " + m);
    System.out.println("N: " + n);
    System.out.println("O: " + o);
    System.out.println("P: " + p);
    System.out.println("Q: " + q);
    System.out.println("R: " + r);
    System.out.println("S: " + s);
    System.out.println("T: " + t);
    System.out.println("U: " + u);
    System.out.println("V: " + v);
    System.out.println("W: " + w); 
    System.out.println("X: " + x);
    System.out.println("Y: " + y);
    System.out.println("Z: " + z);
  
    return total;    
  }  
}
```

My problem is, I can of course concatenate a System.out.println(); with the int vars but it simply prints the number of letters. I don't know ahead of time what people will type so I need my program to detect if the letter = true and thus returns the character and number inside the report.

I've looked for solutions and cannot find a thing. I can't wrap my mind around this yet and frankly I have no idea how to word this inquiry.

**Thank you guys ahead of time**

Comment: Create a HashMap<Char, int> - this will hold the letter as an index, and each time it appears then you should increment the counter. View the Javadoc for HashMap if you are not familiar with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I will have to learn this. I am fairly, fairly new.

Comment: No problem, we all have to start somewhere! Hopefully you can grasp the concept easily enough. Lots of tutorials around HashMaps out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Map to store the characters you have encountered, and how many times they are seen. Using TreeMap will mean that when you iterate over the map the entries are sorted in natural order

```
import java.util.*;

public class CharCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Prompt for user entry
        System.out.println("Enter a phrase: ");
        String letterN = keyboard.nextLine();

        charCount(letterN);
    }


    public static void charCount(String letterN) {
        Map<Character, Long> charMap = new TreeMap<>();
        for (char aChar : letterN.toCharArray()) {
            if (charMap.containsKey(aChar)) {
                charMap.put(aChar, charMap.get(aChar) + 1);
            }
            else {
                charMap.put(aChar, 1L);
            }
            // this if/else can be written using the ternary operator as:
            // charMap.put(aChar, charMap.containsKey(aChar) ? charMap.get(aChar) + 1 : 1L);
        }
        for (Character character : charMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(character + ": " + charMap.get(character));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will venture into this method as well. Thank you for your suggestion!